# How to map level 1 to H1 in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

the default mapping is level 1(==) maps h2 in asciidoc
https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/sections/titles-and-levels/#section-level-syntax

How to map level 1 to H1 when convert .adoc to .html?

I use an [online markdown-like editor](https://yuque.com) which use H1 as section title.

Comment: if you do that, you will also need to find a solution for your title, by default AsciiDoc sets the document title witl level 0 (= my title). What is your motivation for mapping level 1 to h1?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you would likely need to modify the converter.

Currently, the document title converts to H1. If a level 1 heading converts to H1, you'd have to figure out what the level 0 heading converts to.

You haven't stated your goal when making this change. However, if it is presentation-based, you can customize the CSS used to make an H2 look like an H1, continuing through the heading levels to making an H6 look like an H5.